# Where do I ask questions related to producing print-ready graphics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I recently posted a post on creating covers for books for Software Recommendations. I wondered if there are Stack Exchange communities out there that also help fellow Stack Exchangers about the issues related to the printing of those softcopies.

I mean questions like how are the soft copies taken to printing, do they convert our PNG format to something else, how do they handle the hardware with the CMYK when the softcopy had an RGB, etc.

Comment: @Won't, I didn't understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about printing by professionals (printing and publishing), it looks like these questions are on topic on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com); as always, check their [Help Center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there.

Checking the Help Center is especially important as it seems that the focus of Graphic Design Stack Exchange is more on creating than on publishing.

Depending on circumstance, some of it *might* also be on-topic on [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com).

For printing by end-users, on their home printer, you can go to [Super User](https://superuser.com). Super User is a pretty busy site, so take care that your question is not too broad. Make sure it addresses a specific problem. There's a good chance that generic printing questions will be downvoted and closed there. It should help a lot if your question identified a problem on a specific model (or model series) of printer.

Answer (score 3):

Printing related questions are certainly welcome on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), please have a look through previous questions first as there are a number of questions about color conversion, file formats, preparing files for print etc.

Questions about home printers may be ok if you're asking about preparing your files or design considerations, but questions related to the printer itself ("Tech Support" questions are specifically off-topic) would probably be better asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com).